# Thumbnail generation fails on some PDFs

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, pdf, evince

I've noticed that some PDFs won't show a thumbnail no matter what I do; I've tried purging and installing the snap of Evince, only to find that it would result in no thumbnails being generated for PDFs at all.

Most of my PDFs were acquired from Humble Bundles, and some collections have one or two files without thumbnails, others have as many as eight files with no thumbnails; I also tried re-downloading the files, but that didn't help.

Another file without a thumbnail was a fillable PDF that I had edited, but a different fillable PDF that I had also edited did have one.

I've tried using different thumbnailers, deleting old thumbnails... to no avail.

It would seem they also only fail to generate a thumbnail under Ubuntu 18.04, as far as I can tell, anyway.

It's not critical, as I can still read the PDFs, but it's annoying that they don't have thumbnails like the others.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: do you only have the snap version installed? If yes could you see if the thumbnails reappear with the .deb version of evince installed?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that thumbnail generation works for files up to a certain size.

Comment: @ToDo That's not what's happening here, because it happens to both big and small files; there are big files that have thumbnails, and some slightly smaller that do not, as well as very small files that don't, but another around the same size that does.

Comment: @dsSTORM I did reinstall the evince I had from the start, and most of the thumbnails came back, but some still failed to generate.

Comment: PDF is a container format and the contents can vary a lot - try to check what are the common characteristics of the files that don't generate a thumbnail.

Comment: @ToDo I've looked into possible common things, and the best I can come up with is some PDFs of versions above PDF-1.3, regardless of size, page size, color, what program was used to make it, whether it contained a form that was filled out, or whether or not it's optimized, have the possibility to not generate a thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

By installing `dconf-editor` you can change the maximum size in /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/thumbnail-limit

Comment: That is certainly true, but it doesn't solve my issue; I've had some PDF files in excess of 190MB succeed to generate a thumbnail, even when the limit was set to 10 MB, where one at 170MB will not. Furthermore, files way below that limit can also fail to generate a thumbnail.